# How to join LINESTRINGS in a specific order in PostGIS?

Tags: postgis

I have a path from point A to point B, which I want to double back on itself to create a path from A to B back to A.

It seemed like using ST_LineMerge on the MULTILINESTRING created by ST_Collect from the two LINESTRINGS was the answer, however it doesn't appear to maintain the ordering of the paths supplied in the MULTILINESTRING.

For example in psudosql

```
ST_LineMerge(
    MULTILINESTRING(
        (Point A, Point B),
        (Point B, Point A)
    )
)
```

Creates a path B to A to B, as opposed to A to B to A as I would expect based on the LINESTRING order and directions.

How can I reliably join these paths together?

Here is a concrete example...

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING Z ((151.2569403 -33.4921765 14, 151.2568375 -33.4922183 14),(151.2568375 -33.4922183 14, 151.2569403 -33.4921765 14))')));
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(ST_GeomFromText('MULTILINESTRING Z ((151.2568375 -33.4922183 14, 151.2569403 -33.4921765 14), (151.2569403 -33.4921765 14, 151.2568375 -33.4922183 14))')));
```

which both return,

```
LINESTRING Z (151.2568375 -33.4922183 14,151.2569403 -33.4921765 14,151.2568375 -33.4922183 14)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So it seems that the ST_MakeLine function is the answer,

```
ST_MakeLine(
    LINESTRING(Point A, Point B),
    LINESTRING(Point B, Point A)
)
```